# Receive file existence status cannot be determined

Tags: c#, connection, sftp, scp, ssh.net

I have to upload a local file in a sftp folder.
Using SSH.NET I wrote this code

```
using (var client = new ScpClient(host, port, user, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileFullName);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileFullName);

    client.Upload(file, uploadFolder + fileName);
}
```

I can connect and also verified it writing `if (client.IsConnected)`, but I receive the error `Renci.SshNet.Common.ScpException: Receive file existence status cannot be determined`.
The folder is correct (I copied it from FileZilla and `uploadFolder+fileName` return something like `ftpFolder/fileName.txt`) I have authorization (using same credentials, I can put a file in the sftp folder from FileZilla) the local file path is correct (I verified it with debug).
The error is about the `client.Upload()` function.
[image]
It seems that it check if the file exists, but I don't want to change an existing file, I want to upload a new one.
Is it the wrong method?
I also tryied this code

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, user, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(fileFullName))
    {
        client.UploadFile(fs, uploadFolder, true);
    }
}
```

but I receive `System.Exception: 'General failure '` (always in `client.Upload`
Can someone help me?

Comment: Does you question include all of the relevant code? What line of code is producing the "Renci.SshNet.Common.ScpException: Receive file existence..." message? Is there a stack trace along with the message? Nothing that you've posted appears to test whether a file exists.

Comment: Yes this is all the relevant code. I receive the error on `client.Upload(file, uploadFolder + fileName);` The rest of code make the file to transfer, import host, port, admin and user from App.Config and do other stuff. The rest of code was yet working for it's purpose, I've add a function just to connect to sftp and to send there the file and it's this one.  I will update the question adding this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.
I had to use SftpClient, not ScpClient that's not working for me.
To solve the General failure, it simply needed to insert the buffer size!
Working code:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileFullName);

using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, user, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(fileFullName))
    {
        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
        client.UploadFile(fs, uploadFolder + fileName);
    }
}
```